# Robotium recorder Ubuntu Issue

Tags: android, testing, recorder

I installed JDK and eclipse and `-java version` seems to work in terminal but I am not finding a single reason as to why Robotium recorder even after installation from Help->install new software in eclipse isn't visible in right click menu as well as File->new->Other->

Please tell me what to do. I have Ubuntu 12.10

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Robotium Recorder has now been released for Android Studio. You can try it and see if it works better for you.

http://robotium.com/pages/installation-android-studio